# Asterisks in HTML Element Class Names

Tags: html

Reviewing Zappos.com's source, I noticed they have many html elements using class names like:

`class='gae-click*-*Promos*Join-Zappos-Rewards-Earn-Points-Get-Free-Expedited-Shipping-and-more-Learn-More- images '`

I know asterisks can be used in css files themselves, for selectors, but I'm unfamiliar with this on page elements.

Is it a wildcard or something? Or is it just the name of a single class?

Comment: Just the name of a single class

Comment: @Dekel Any ideas why they separate everything with *'s then? Seems... odd?

Comment: might be a specific framework they are using the split by `*` and bind events or something based on that.

Comment: @Sure, added...

Comment: Unfortunately, all 3 answers have 1/3rd of the answer! Looking for someone to combine the other points into a single, concise answer.

Comment: You know, you can edit the answers and add the missing data :)

Comment: @Dekel I'd be picking a favorite then ;-P

Comment: Added a few more lines there, hope you feel the answer is more complete now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` sign is a valid value for class attributes, the usage in Zappos.com's website is probably related to the framework they are using (maybe split by `*` to bind some events, like `click` or something).

While checking the `CSS` there is no definitions related to the classes with the `*` chars.

Using a `class-with-very-long-definition-regarding-some-element` can help during development in case you need to relations between elements. This is exactly the same as adding a `data` attribute if you don't really use it.

A nice use-case is to filter by "keywords" inside the class-names to add events (such as click/hover, using `class*="click"`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

As per HTML5 rules, an asterisk is an acceptable value for the `class` attribute.

Here's a complete explanation: [HTML5: Permitted Values for ID & Class Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31773673/3597276)

Answer (score 1):

The class **gae-click*Global-Header-zapposheader*Promos*Join-Zappos-Rewards-Earn-Points-Get-Free-Expedited-Shipping-and-more-Learn-More- images**

is attached to an **image** element in the (potentially **global**) **header** with an alt tag (and title) of **Join Zappos Rewards: Earn Points, Get Free Expedited Shipping, and more! Learn More.**

Seems like they are just using an overly specific lexagon based class to me.

Though it does seem plausible that they might then select on class^="gae-click" or class~="*Promos*"